# How to I include a vbscript step in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vbscript

What I'm trying to do:
I have 3 xls files, i get by email, named as such (date stamp changes every time):

```
CDC aaa 01 01 2018.xls
CDC bbb 01 01 2018.xls
CDC ccc 01 01 2018.xls
```

I want to:

- convert them to csv
- name them so: aaa.csv, bbb.csv, ccc.csv

Here's my script, so far, that fails:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion


for %%F in ("*.xls") do ( 
    REM get filename only
    set tmp=%%~F

    REM look for aaa
    echo.!tmp! | findstr /i "aaa" 1>nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo. Not aaa.
    ) ELSE (
        echo. Found aaa
        set fileout=aaa.csv
    )

    REM look for bbb
    echo.!tmp! | findstr /i "bbb" 1>nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo. Not bbb.
    ) ELSE (
        echo. Found bbb.
        set fileout=bbb.csv
    )

    REM look for ccc
    echo.!tmp! | findstr /i "ccc" 1>nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo. Not ccc.
    ) ELSE (
        echo. Found ccc.
        set fileout=ccc.csv
    )
    REM convert and rename file
    xlstocsv.vbs "!tmp!" "!fileout!"
)
```

When I run this I get a **Windows Script Host** error message saying:

```
Script: C:\[bla]\xlstocsv.vbs
Line: 17
Char: 1
Error: The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:
- Make sure folder exists
- Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only
- Make sure the file name does not contain anu of the following characters: < > ? [ ] : CDC aaa 01 01 2018.xls or *
- Make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters
- Code: 800A03EC
- Source: Microsoft Excel
```

I can confirm the files/folder is not read only, I can confirm there are no special characters in the path/filename, nor is the path longer than 218 characters.

I can also confirm that the excel files are not corrupt or bad in any way.

I can also say that while I see the error message, if I try to open ANY of the 3 files in excel (not just the one I get the error for), excel throws the exact same error as above.

If I run this script, it works just fine:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for %%F in ("*.xls") do ( 
    xlstocsv.vbs "%%~nF.xls" "%%~nF.csv"
)
```

but this version of the script does not rename my files to the desired filenames, just changes the extension.

Here's the VBScript:

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please specify the source and the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

csv_format = 6

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Just add cscript before xlstocsv.vbs

Comment: What happens if there's more than one `.xls` file with a name beginning with `ABC`? If there definitely cannot be more than one, why aren't you using `("ABC*.xls")`? _There's no need to set a `tmp` variable then or to do an `If` comparison_, you could use something like: `For %%F In ("ABC*.xls") Do CScript //B //NoLogo xlsToCSV.vbs "%%F" ABC.csv`.

Comment: @RegisDesrosiers i changed that last line to "cscript xlstocsv.vbs ..." but it didn't work: xlstocsv.vbs(17, 1) Microsoft Excel: The fi
le could not be accessed. Try one of the following: [bla bla]. the files are 'locked' because of the loop i guess.

Comment: @Compo that was just the generic example. I have 3 files that need to be processed twice weekly. They come in as "bla A/B/C bla 01 01 2000.xls" So i want to convert them to csv and rename them as a.csv, b.csv, c.csv. That's why I have the if statement, to check and see which file I'm looping over and rename it as needed. i did try cscript xlstocs.vbs but i get the same error about the file being locked, unaccessible.

Comment: I modified the batch script so that the for loop only renames the files as i need them and then, outside of the for loop I run the xlstocsv.vbs command on each file individually. No luck, the files are still 'locked', if i let the batch file finish and run a different one that just does the vbscript step then that works.

Comment: @SergiuZ, if you only have three files and they only need to be processed twice a week, how difficult can it be to not open them during, or ensure that they're not in use before? Have you considered copying the files and processing the copies? Why use generic examples for a specific issue? _Do you really think that someboidy could steal corporate information by knowing those file names?_ Also if there are only three files why do you not know their names? _You could then just run the conversion command on three lines instead of in a loop with wildcards!_

Comment: There is no way the batch file is locking the files. The batch file code never attempts to read or write the input or output files.  Only your Vbscript reads and writes the files.

Comment: @Compo I modified my question to show exactly! what I'm doing, what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @Squashman edited my question to shoe exactly what I'm doing. Why does the second script work while the first throws an error?

Comment: The most likely cause of the problem is that VBScripts are by default run with `wscript.exe`, which runs asynchronously (i.e. the call returns immediately while the program continues running in the background). Use `cscript.exe` as the first comment suggests to avoid that. Other possible issues are the VBScript not closing the file correctly or a background Excel instance keeping it open, but for troubleshooting that we'd need to see the VBScript code.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i added the vbscript to the question as well. It's worth noting I tried adding "cscript.exe" right in front of xlstocsv.vbs and it didn't work. I also tried, using the loop to just rename the files first and then manually call, at the very end, xlstocsv.vbs aaa.xls aaa.csv (with and without cscript) and it didn't work, same error.

Comment: I would put a `wscript.echo src_file` and `wscript.echo dest_file` in your vbscript.  That may show you the problem.  And you should definitely use `cscript` to launch the vbs.

Answer (score 1):

Given the provided file naming structure, the following script should perform the task required:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Ext1=.xls"
Set "Ext2=.csv"
Set "ScrV=C:\bla\xlsToCSV.vbs"
Set "SrcD=C:\bla\bla"
Set "Str1=aaa"
Set "Str2=bbb"
Set "Str3=ccc"

CD /D "%SrcD%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
For %%A In ("?* %Str1% ?*%Ext1%","?* %Str2% ?*%Ext1%","?* %Str3% ?*%Ext1%") Do (
    For /F "Tokens=2" %%B In ("%%~nA") Do (Echo Found %%B
        CScript //B //NoLogo "%ScrV%" "%%A" "%%B%Ext2%"))
```

You should change only the lines `4`-`8`, by inserting the appropriate paths and strings. *(Please do not add or remove any doublequotes, `"`, and do not include a trailing backslash, `\` on your source directory path on line `5`.)

This is only a batch script solution, VBScript Excel or filesystem issues would require a new question.*